# Pandas mapping with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe consisting of **Year**, **Month**, **Temperature**. Now, I need to create seasonal means, such as *DJF* (Dec, Jan, Feb), *MAM* (Mar, Apr, May), *JJA* (Jun, Jul, Aug), *SON* (Sep, Oct, Nov).

But how can I take into account the fact that DJF should have December from the previous year, January and February of the subsequent year?

This is the code I have so far:

```
z = {1: 'DJF', 2: 'DJF', 3: 'MAM', 4: 'MAM', 5: 'MAM', 6: 'JJA', 7: 'JJA', 8: 'JJA', 9: 'SON', 10: 'SON',
11: 'SON', 12: 'DJF'}
df['season'] = df['Mon'].map(z)
```

The problem with the above coding is that when I group by year and season to calculate the means, the values for DJF will be incorrect, since they take Dec, Jan, and Feb of the same year.

```
df.groupby(['Year','season']).mean()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can create periodindex by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)

Then [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) one moth and convert to `Quarters` by [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html).

Last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by index anf aggregate `mean`:

```
df['Day'] = 1
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year','Month','Day']]).dt.to_period('M')
df = df.shift(1, freq='M').asfreq('Q')

print (df.groupby(level=0)['Temperature'].mean())
```

Sample:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=20, freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'Temperature': range(20)})  
df['Year'] = df.Date.dt.year
df['Month'] = df.Date.dt.month
df = df.drop('Date', axis=1)
print (df)
    Temperature  Year  Month
0             0  2017      4
1             1  2017      5
2             2  2017      6
3             3  2017      7
4             4  2017      8
5             5  2017      9
6             6  2017     10
7             7  2017     11
8             8  2017     12
9             9  2018      1
10           10  2018      2
11           11  2018      3
12           12  2018      4
13           13  2018      5
14           14  2018      6
15           15  2018      7
16           16  2018      8
17           17  2018      9
18           18  2018     10
19           19  2018     11
```

---

```
df['Day'] = 1
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year','Month','Day']]).dt.to_period('M')
df = df.shift(1, freq='M').asfreq('Q')
print (df)
        Temperature  Year  Month  Day
2017Q2            0  2017      4    1
2017Q2            1  2017      5    1
2017Q3            2  2017      6    1
2017Q3            3  2017      7    1
2017Q3            4  2017      8    1
2017Q4            5  2017      9    1
2017Q4            6  2017     10    1
2017Q4            7  2017     11    1
2018Q1            8  2017     12    1
2018Q1            9  2018      1    1
2018Q1           10  2018      2    1
2018Q2           11  2018      3    1
2018Q2           12  2018      4    1
2018Q2           13  2018      5    1
2018Q3           14  2018      6    1
2018Q3           15  2018      7    1
2018Q3           16  2018      8    1
2018Q4           17  2018      9    1
2018Q4           18  2018     10    1
2018Q4           19  2018     11    1
```

---

```
print (df.groupby(level=0)['Temperature'].mean())
2017Q2     0.5
2017Q3     3.0
2017Q4     6.0
2018Q1     9.0
2018Q2    12.0
2018Q3    15.0
2018Q4    18.0
Freq: Q-DEC, Name: Temperature, dtype: float64
```

And last if need `season` column:

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0)['Temperature'].mean().rename_axis('per').reset_index()
z = {1: 'DJF',2: 'MAM', 3: 'JJA', 4: 'SON'}
df1['season'] = df1['per'].dt.quarter.map(z)
df1['yaer'] = df1['per'].dt.year
print (df1)
     per  Temperature season  yaer
0 2017Q2          0.5    MAM  2017
1 2017Q3          3.0    JJA  2017
2 2017Q4          6.0    SON  2017
3 2018Q1          9.0    DJF  2018
4 2018Q2         12.0    MAM  2018
5 2018Q3         15.0    JJA  2018
6 2018Q4         18.0    SON  2018
```

Comment: I like your question, really interesting! Good luck!